# HTTP response issue

Tags: angularjs

[image]I have used restapi to fetch the response from the server. When I make a call on the client side I am the getting the required reponse object, but the data is not getting displayed. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
app.controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {           
  $http({
         url: '//localhost:800/psp/policies',
         method: 'GET',
    }).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.bankpolicy = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        },
          function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log("Error:" + response.data)
    })
}]);
```

HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-8 txt" ng-controller="Ctrl">
<table class="table-write">
  <thead class="rowhead"> 
    <tr>
      <th class="mid">Sl.</th>
      <th id="tnm">PolicyName</th>
      <th class="mid">date_of_issue</th>
      <th class="mid">description</th>
      <th class="mid">View</th>
      <th class="mid">Process</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="bank in bankpolicy">
      <td>{{bank.id}}</td>
      <td>{{bank.policy_name}}</td>
      <td>{{bank.date_of_issue}}</td>
      <td>{{bank.description}}</td>
      <td>{{bank.view}}</td>
      <td>{{bank.process}}</td>          
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what gives you console.log($scope) in successCallback

Comment: response object . @mr.void

Comment: are you sure? $scope should give you a scope Object of your current scope. Can you provide an example?

Comment: show the console output you get

Comment: bankpolicy: [0: object {id:1, policy_name: "API", date_of_issue:"2010-10-14T18:30:00.000Z", description:"The Government of India has announced a new scheme called Atal Pension Yojana (APY).", 1: object {id:2, policy_name: "PMI", date_of_issue:"2010-10-14T18:30:00.000Z", description:"Pradhan Mantri Suraksha Bima Yojana is basically an Accidental Death Insurance policy."]

Comment: @AlekseySolovey. That's why i used console to check where I am getting empty object or not. But I am getting the response object

Comment: can you paste your response from Network tab on browser instead of console.

Comment: @Ved I have attached the response that I am getting .

Comment: instead of screenshot can paste data from network tab in browser console. When you hit URL go to nework tab and select the url which you just u hit. And copy the response from there.

Comment: Try what I have updated in mys answer. Also check   console.log(response.data.bankpolicy);

Comment: Look like `data` actually holds a `bankpolicy` itself  `$scope.bankpolicy = response.data.bankpolicy` would work...

Comment: answer what is given by david is correct. It solved my issue

Comment: you are getting object array with object bankpolicy so. you should call response.data.bankpolicy.

Answer (score 2):

After looking to response it looks like this the response is `Object` that contains `bankpolicy` as `array` inside it as property.

```
<tr ng-repeat="bank in bankpolicy.bankpolicy">
//code
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes. It is an Array. OP initially added comment that it is object.